# Locating the end points of a bridge-like structure in an image

Tags: algorithm, image, language-agnostic, image-processing

How do I locate the end points of a bridge-like structure in an image?

*Below is a generalized representation.*

[image]

I have a set of images that look like what you see on the left hand column as shown in the above picture. What I am trying to detect/locate is actually the two endpoints that are shown on the right hand column in the above picture. It's quite like locating the "two ends points" of the 'bridge'.

I have applied some basic morphological operations; however, either I'm doing it wrong or those basic morphological operations aren't working in this scenario. (I have tried making it into skeletons; however, once the skeletons are formed, I can't seem to detect the cross with three edges).

### ***EDITS***

Thanks for the previous suggestion; however, it looks like the original sets of images cannot be completely generalized like what I'd previously drawn.

I have attached the latest updates to this question. Below is a more detailed representation that includes the original segmented regions and the corresponding images that'd undergone a "thinning" morphological operation. Again, the left side is the originally segmented region; while on the right would be the points to be detected.

[image]

Comment: FWIW its hardly too localised.  I've asked lots of image analysis and opencv questions here and got good replies.  As the major in on this site is by search, visitors tend to find the questions they want answered by search not browsing, so this is hardly harmful even if 99% of SO is about .NET ;)

Comment: Hi Gary, can you give us a bit more detail on what you are trying to accomplish and how you are defining the target points? Some of the cases you posted look a bit ambiguous to me. Are these medical images of some sort? Also, could you post a link to some full-resolution test images?

Comment: Re your new images, perhaps you should explain _in words_ why are you selecting those junctions where there are three or more (in the skeleton). At first sight, your choose seems inconsistent. (I mean: I don't understand it, which is a pretty bad definition of inconsistency, BTW :)

Comment: @belisarius.  Thanks, actually, im interested in getting all of the junctions(if not the right one yet.  The correctness is defined by the expertise) at this stage.

Comment: @zephyr.  Thanks, yes these are processed medical images.  And, i don't quite have the access to the full-resolution test images.  I believe, at this stage, im required to pinpoint all of the junctions first, then filter out those junctions by the expertise later.  I too find it hard to trace for the consistency of the pins.  Thanks very much!

Comment: @Gary ok, if you can tolerate some false positives at this stage I think locating the junctions is doable - but from the examples you gave I don't see a good definition that would select only the points you circled without some more information.

Comment: @zephyr, i agree with you, without external input or more details from the expertise, it is almost impossible to differentiate a junction from another.

Comment: @zephyr, regarding false positives, i agree with you on that one as well.  thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a code example to locate branch points after skeletonizing the image:

```
import pymorph as m
import mahotas
from numpy import array

image = mahotas.imread('1.png') # load image

b1 = image[:,:,1] < 150 # make binary image from thresholded green channel

b2 = m.thin(b1) # create skeleton
b3 = m.thin(b2, m.endpoints('homotopic'), 15) # prune small branches, may need tuning

# structuring elements to search for 3-connected pixels
seA1 = array([[False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

seB1 = array([[False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)

seA2 = array([[False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

seB2 = array([[ True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)

# hit or miss templates from these SEs
hmt1 = m.se2hmt(seA1, seB1)
hmt2 = m.se2hmt(seA2, seB2)

# locate 3-connected regions
b4 = m.union(m.supcanon(b3, hmt1), m.supcanon(b3, hmt2))

# dilate to merge nearby hits
b5 = m.dilate(b4, m.sedisk(10))

# locate centroids
b6 = m.blob(m.label(b5), 'centroid')

outputimage = m.overlay(b1, m.dilate(b6,m.sedisk(5)))
mahotas.imsave('output.png', outputimage)
```

[image: sample output]
[image: sample output]

Answer (score 7):

Solution using Python, [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy), [Pymorph](http://luispedro.org/software/pymorph) and [Mahotas](http://luispedro.org/software/mahotas):

```
import pymorph as m
import mahotas
from numpy import where, reshape

image = mahotas.imread('input.png') # Load image

b1 = image[:,:,0] < 100 # Make a binary image from the thresholded red channel
b2 = m.erode(b1, m.sedisk(4)) # Erode to enhance contrast of the bridge
b3 = m.open(b2,m.sedisk(4)) # Remove the bridge
b4 = b2-b3 # Bridge plus small noise
b5 = m.areaopen(b4,1000) # Remove small areas leaving only a thinned bridge
b6 = m.dilate(b3)*b5 # Extend the non-bridge area slightly and get intersection with the bridge.

#b6 is image of end of bridge, now find single points
b7 = m.thin(b6, m.endpoints('homotopic')) # Narrow regions to single points.
labelled = m.label(b7) # Label endpoints.

x1, y1 = reshape(where(labelled == 1),(1,2))[0]
x2, y2 = reshape(where(labelled == 2),(1,2))[0]

outputimage = m.overlay(b1, m.dilate(b7,m.sedisk(5)))
mahotas.imsave('output.png', outputimage)
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a code example in [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), probably not optimal:

```
f[i_] := 
   Module[{t, i2, w, z, neighbours, i3, cRed}, 
  (t = Thinning[ColorNegate@i, 15]; 
   i2 = ImageData@Binarize[ DeleteSmallComponents[
        ImageSubtract[t, Dilation[Erosion[t, 1], 1]], 100], .1];

    For[w = 2, w < Dimensions[i2][[1]], w++,
     For[z = 2, z < Dimensions[i2][[2]], z++,
      If[i2[[w, z]] == 1 && i2[[w + 1, z + 1]] == 1, 
         i2[[w, z + 1]] = i2[[w + 1, z]] = 0];
      If[i2[[w, z]] == i2[[w - 1, z - 1]] == 1, 
         i2[[w, z - 1]] = i2[[w - 1, z]] = 0];
      If[i2[[w, z]] == i2[[w + 1, z - 1]] == 1, 
         i2[[w, z - 1]] = i2[[w + 1, z]] = 0];
      If[i2[[w, z]] == i2[[w - 1, z + 1]] == 1, 
         i2[[w, z + 1]] = i2[[w - 1, z]] = 0];
      ]
     ];

    neighbours[l_, k_, j_] := 
      l[[k - 1, j]] +     l[[k + 1, j]] +     l[[k, j + 1]] + l[[k, j - 1]] + 
      l[[k + 1, j + 1]] + l[[k + 1, j - 1]] + l[[k - 1, j + 1]] + 
      l[[k - 1, j - 1]];

    i3 = Table[
      If[i2[[w, z]] ==1,neighbours[i2, w, z], 0],{w,2,Dimensions[i2][[1]]-1}, 
                                                 {z,2,Dimensions[i2][[2]]-1}];
    cRed = 
     ColorNegate@Rasterize[Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}], ImageSize -> 15];

    ImageCompose[
     ImageCompose[i, 
      cRed, {#[[2]], Dimensions[i2][[1]] - #[[1]]} &@
       Position[i3, 1][[1]]], 
      cRed, {#[[2]], Dimensions[i2][[1]] - #[[1]]} &@
       Position[i3, 1][[2]]])];
```

[image]

Comment: im not entirely proficient in mathmatica; however, i see that the image is opened and being subtracted from the original image for removing noise, and there's 8 neightbors SE.  And then i cannot tell what should be next.  Will you please kindly elaborate further?

Comment: @Gary I posted this in a hurry. Sorry. I'll elaborate as soon as I get some free time

Answer (score 1):

A generic approach comes to mind:

1) trace the outline and turn it into a path.  So there is one path that goes all around the shape, it being made out of line segments

2) look for the stem - the place on the path where the line segments are approximately parallel for some distance (a spatial index e.g. octree or kdtree will help keep the search localised)

3) follow the path in some direction until the two sides suddenly diverge.  That's an endpoint to the stem

4) follow the path in the other direction to find the other endpoint

Comment: i quite like the path idea; however, would you  mind elaborate more about how you detect/localize where the merge is(since, if we turn that into a path, the end points, that i need, would be the place for two branches/edges to merge into 1, i imagine).  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try running a moving window over the image with a filter that is sum of the pixel values inside. Tune the size to say double the size of the bridge width. You should expect to see a fairly sharp transition when you run off the bridge onto the shore.

Comment: thanks.  Yes, i have tried that in my attempt ; however, since the 'bridge' could rotate, as shown in the above pictures, it is very hard to pinpoint the two peaks as the end points.

Answer (score 0):

One interesting feature that found is the junction point in the skeleton which has the least value of the distance function of the complement of the object associated with it.

X - object set in black in input image
D(X) - Distance function of object X
D(~X) - Distance function of the complement of the object - this would usually resemble the skeletonization of the object set by itself.

Thus the basic intuition here is that the object X's topology is such that near the heavy heads one finds pinch - a place where you are sure to have a junction point in the skeleton - and at the same time a low value of the distance function of the complement of the object. The neck or pinch produces a minimum here at the junction point.

Maybe this idea needs some tuning - but i guess one can work around.