# How can i find junction points in a skeletonized image?

Tags: python, image-processing

I found  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173424/locating-the-end-points-of-a-bridge-like-structure-in-an-image) a code for finding junction points of a skeletonized image.

The code doesn't find all junctions but only the main junction point.

How can i adapt this code for finding all junction points in a skeleton image?

In my sample image: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByS6Z5WRz-h2U3NBWWZ6V3FqeUk/edit?usp=sharing i suppose to find at least 6 junctions in the skeleton!

My code:

Before finding junction i prepare the image: i convert in binary, filling the holes and skeletonizing.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
import cv2
import pymorph as m
import mahotas
import scipy.ndimage.morphology as mo


def skeletonize(img):
    h1 = np.array([[0, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0],[1, 1, 1]]) 
    m1 = np.array([[1, 1, 1],[0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0]]) 
    h2 = np.array([[0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 0],[0, 1, 0]]) 
    m2 = np.array([[0, 1, 1],[0, 0, 1],[0, 0, 0]])    
    hit_list = [] 
    miss_list = []
    for k in range(4): 
        hit_list.append(np.rot90(h1, k))
        hit_list.append(np.rot90(h2, k))
        miss_list.append(np.rot90(m1, k))
        miss_list.append(np.rot90(m2, k))    
    img = img.copy()
    while True:
        last = img
        for hit, miss in zip(hit_list, miss_list): 
            hm = mo.binary_hit_or_miss(img, hit, miss) 
            img = np.logical_and(img, np.logical_not(hm)) 
        if np.all(img == last):  
            break
    return img

#input image
nomeimg = 'DUPLInuova/fionda 3/c (3).jpg'
img = cv2.imread(nomeimg)
gray = cv2.imread(nomeimg,0)
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(6,6)) #con 4,4 si vede tutta la stella e riconosce piccoli oggetti
graydilate = cv2.erode(gray, element) #imgbnbin

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(graydilate,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) 
imgbnbin = thresh

cv2.imshow('binaria',imgbnbin)
cv2.waitKey()





#finding a unique contour
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print(len(contours))

Areacontours = list()
calcarea = 0.0
unicocnt = 0.0
for i in range (0, len(contours)):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
    if (area > 90 ):  #con 90 trova i segni e togli puntini
        if (calcarea<area):
            calcarea = area
            unicocnt = contours[i]

cnt = unicocnt            
print(len(cnt))
cv2.drawContours(thresh,contours,-1,(0,255,0),3)

#fill holes
des = imgbnbin
cv2.drawContours(des,[unicocnt],0,255,-1)

gray = cv2.bitwise_not(des)

cv2.imshow('gray tappabuchi grAY',gray)
cv2.waitKey()


kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(3,3))
res = cv2.morphologyEx(gray,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel)

cv2.imshow('res tappabuchi',res)
cv2.waitKey()

rest = cv2.bitwise_not(res)

print(rest)


cv2.imshow('rest tappabuchi 2',rest)
cv2.waitKey()

skel = skeletonize(rest)
skel = skel.astype(np.uint8)*255
print(skel)
cv2.imshow('skel',skel)
cv2.waitKey(0)

imgbnbin = m.binary(skel)

#FINDING junction and PRUNING
print("mohatas imgbnbin")
print(imgbnbin)

b2 = m.thin(imgbnbin)
b3 = m.thin(b2, m.endpoints('homotopic'), 15) # prune small branches, may need tuning

outputimage = m.overlay(imgbnbin, b3)
mahotas.imsave('outputs.png', outputimage)

# structuring elements to search for 3-connected pixels
seA1 = array([[False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

seB1 = array([[False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)

seA2 = array([[False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

seB2 = array([[ True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)

# hit or miss templates from these SEs
hmt1 = m.se2hmt(seA1, seB1)
hmt2 = m.se2hmt(seA2, seB2)

# locate 3-connected regions
b4 = m.union(m.supcanon(b3, hmt1), m.supcanon(b3, hmt2))

# dilate to merge nearby hits
b5 = m.dilate(b4, m.sedisk(10))

# locate centroids
b6 = m.blob(m.label(b5), 'centroid')

outputimage = m.overlay(imgbnbin, m.dilate(b6,m.sedisk(5)))
mahotas.imsave('output.png', outputimage)
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43037692) question seems related.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, A junction point in a skeleton is a pixel that has more than 2 black pixels as neighbors (if background = white and skeleton = black).

So a simple solution is to iterate through the black pixels, and calculate the number of black pixels surrounding the current pixel. Need code for that? the code you use for skeletonization  could be modified to do this.