# How to find branch point from binary skeletonize image

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I use Python OpenCV to skeletonize an image like this:

[image: This is the skeletonized image]

and I want to find the branch point of the skeleton

[image: This is the point that I wanted]

I have no idea how to do it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

This question is already quite old but if anyone else stumbles across this and would like to have an answer that does not rely on additional packages and uses simple morphological operations you might find the following helpful.

The idea is simply to apply a hit-or-miss transform to search for pixels that satisfy the condition of a branchpoint. A branchpoint in a skeleton is a pixel that is connected to three or four other pixels. Given a list of appropriate structuring elements `selems` you can elegantly combine several hit-or-miss transforms in one output image like the following.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndi


branches = np.zeros_like(skeleton, dtype=bool)
for selem in selems:
    branches |= ndi.binary_hit_or_miss(skeleton, selem)
```

This is quite space efficient because you directly add the result of each transform to the same result array. The question now is how to create the list of structuring elements. One solution would be the following.

```
selems = list()
selems.append(np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]]))
selems.append(np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]]))
selems.append(np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]))
selems.append(np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]))
selems.append(np.array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]]))
selems = [np.rot90(selems[i], k=j) for i in range(5) for j in range(4)]

selems.append(np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]]))
selems.append(np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]))
```

The last two lines are only needed if you want to also detect branch points with four branches. If you're only interested in three branches you can omit the last two lines.

The complete solution would then be

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndi


selems = list()
selems.append(np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]]))
selems.append(np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]]))
selems.append(np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]))
selems.append(np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]))
selems.append(np.array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]]))
selems = [np.rot90(selems[i], k=j) for i in range(5) for j in range(4)]

selems.append(np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]]))
selems.append(np.array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]))

branches = np.zeros_like(skeleton, dtype=bool)
for selem in selems:
    branches |= ndi.binary_hit_or_miss(skeleton, selem)
```

Likewise you can search for endpoints by using the following list of structuring elements.

```
selems = list()
selems.append(np.array([[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]]))
selems.append(np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]]))
selems = [np.rot90(selems[i], k=j) for i in range(2) for j in range(4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library [Skan](https://jni.github.io/skan/index.html) to find the branch points.

```
from skan import skeleton_to_csgraph
from skimage import io, morphology

# loading image
image = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpSt9.jpg')

# make image binary
image_binary = image >= 200

# skeletonize
sk = morphology.skeletonize(image_binary).astype(bool)

# receive a degree matrix
_, _, degrees = skeleton_to_csgraph(sk)

# consider all values larger than two as intersection
intersection_matrix = degrees > 2
```

The result here is not a single pixel as multiple branches meet at one point. One could determine this center region with [regionprops](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops) and then find the centroid if one needs exactly one pixel.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea here is to look in the neighborhood. You can use a 8-conected neighborhood for every pixels ([1 1 1; 1 1 1; 1 1 1], and the center is the pixel for which the neighborhood being explored!).

At every branch point, the degree of the pixel will be > 2, while regular pixels will have a degree of 2 (i.e., connected to 2 pixels in their neighborhood).

In your case your objective is finding a 'crossing point', where the degree is > 3.

Answer (score 0):

I found all the answers above a bit too technical. Here is a way to do this in the simplest terms I could think of.

First we need to agree on what a branch point is. A branch point in a binary image (matrix of `0`'s and `1`s) is a `1` with at least three other `1`'s in its neighborhood.

We also need to agree on how to discern neighboring pixels (top/bottom/left/right only,
or with added diagonally adjacent pixels). This is up to us.

Having agreed on the above, we can now detect the branch points in the image.

1. Traverse the image skipping zero pixels (these can't be branch
   points)
2. At each `1` look around its neighborhood. How many `1`s are there?
3. Let's use our definition to answer the  question: If there are at least three `1`s you've found a branch point!

Answer (score -2):

Output (overlaid on input image):

[image]

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Find branch point in example image.
"""

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mahotas.morph import hitmiss as hit_or_miss
from skimage.morphology import medial_axis as skeletonize
# from scipy.ndimage import binary_hit_or_miss as hit_or_miss

def find_branch_points(skel):
    X=[]
    #cross X
    X0 = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 1, 1],
                   [0, 1, 0]])
    X1 = np.array([[1, 0, 1],
                   [0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 0, 1]])
    X.append(X0)
    X.append(X1)
    #T like
    T=[]
    #T0 contains X0
    T0=np.array([[2, 1, 2],
                 [1, 1, 1],
                 [2, 2, 2]])

    T1=np.array([[1, 2, 1],
                 [2, 1, 2],
                 [1, 2, 2]])  # contains X1

    T2=np.array([[2, 1, 2],
                 [1, 1, 2],
                 [2, 1, 2]])

    T3=np.array([[1, 2, 2],
                 [2, 1, 2],
                 [1, 2, 1]])

    T4=np.array([[2, 2, 2],
                 [1, 1, 1],
                 [2, 1, 2]])

    T5=np.array([[2, 2, 1],
                 [2, 1, 2],
                 [1, 2, 1]])

    T6=np.array([[2, 1, 2],
                 [2, 1, 1],
                 [2, 1, 2]])

    T7=np.array([[1, 2, 1],
                 [2, 1, 2],
                 [2, 2, 1]])
    T.append(T0)
    T.append(T1)
    T.append(T2)
    T.append(T3)
    T.append(T4)
    T.append(T5)
    T.append(T6)
    T.append(T7)
    #Y like
    Y=[]
    Y0=np.array([[1, 0, 1],
                 [0, 1, 0],
                 [2, 1, 2]])

    Y1=np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                 [1, 1, 2],
                 [0, 2, 1]])

    Y2=np.array([[1, 0, 2],
                 [0, 1, 1],
                 [1, 0, 2]])

    Y2=np.array([[1, 0, 2],
                 [0, 1, 1],
                 [1, 0, 2]])

    Y3=np.array([[0, 2, 1],
                 [1, 1, 2],
                 [0, 1, 0]])

    Y4=np.array([[2, 1, 2],
                 [0, 1, 0],
                 [1, 0, 1]])
    Y5=np.rot90(Y3)
    Y6 = np.rot90(Y4)
    Y7 = np.rot90(Y5)
    Y.append(Y0)
    Y.append(Y1)
    Y.append(Y2)
    Y.append(Y3)
    Y.append(Y4)
    Y.append(Y5)
    Y.append(Y6)
    Y.append(Y7)

    bp = np.zeros(skel.shape, dtype=int)
    for x in X:
        bp = bp + hit_or_miss(skel,x)
    for y in Y:
        bp = bp + hit_or_miss(skel,y)
    for t in T:
        bp = bp + hit_or_miss(skel,t)

    return bp

def find_end_points(skel):
    endpoint1=np.array([[0, 0, 0],
                        [0, 1, 0],
                        [2, 1, 2]])

    endpoint2=np.array([[0, 0, 0],
                        [0, 1, 2],
                        [0, 2, 1]])

    endpoint3=np.array([[0, 0, 2],
                        [0, 1, 1],
                        [0, 0, 2]])

    endpoint4=np.array([[0, 2, 1],
                        [0, 1, 2],
                        [0, 0, 0]])

    endpoint5=np.array([[2, 1, 2],
                        [0, 1, 0],
                        [0, 0, 0]])

    endpoint6=np.array([[1, 2, 0],
                        [2, 1, 0],
                        [0, 0, 0]])

    endpoint7=np.array([[2, 0, 0],
                        [1, 1, 0],
                        [2, 0, 0]])

    endpoint8=np.array([[0, 0, 0],
                        [2, 1, 0],
                        [1, 2, 0]])

    ep1=hit_or_miss(skel,endpoint1)
    ep2=hit_or_miss(skel,endpoint2)
    ep3=hit_or_miss(skel,endpoint3)
    ep4=hit_or_miss(skel,endpoint4)
    ep5=hit_or_miss(skel,endpoint5)
    ep6=hit_or_miss(skel,endpoint6)
    ep7=hit_or_miss(skel,endpoint7)
    ep8=hit_or_miss(skel,endpoint8)
    ep = ep1+ep2+ep3+ep4+ep5+ep6+ep7+ep8
    return ep

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# script
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

img = plt.imread("test.jpg")

# for some reason (screenshot?), example image is not binary
binary = img >= 250

skeleton = skeletonize(binary)

branch_pts = find_branch_points(skeleton)

plt.imshow(binary + branch_pts, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest'); plt.show()
```

Comment: You should say a few words about what you are doing. Just slamming in some uncommented code won't help someone who is not able to solve that problem on his own.