# CV: Find intersections and end points in a maze image by using spatial filtering and matrix operation

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

How to use spatial filtering and matrix operation to find the intersection (red points) and end points (blue points)

[image: Maze example]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43037692/how-to-find-branch-point-from-binary-skeletonize-image and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705405/finding-intersections-of-a-skeletonised-image-in-python-opencv

Comment: the question appears to be missing code or an attempt at the problem...

Comment: please take the [tour] and review [ask] and [mre] and whatever else might be interesting in the [help]